What is the origin of the many extra mnemonics in Manx Software Systems’ 8086 assembler?
While I was viewing the file AS.EXE, I stumbled upon next list of instruction mnemonics for the 8086 processor:

ja jb jc je jg jl in jo jp js jz 
aaa daa aad adc add dec bge aam jae jbe lea clc bhi ble cmc 
cld bne aas jge sbb beq das cli jna neg jnb inc jhi jnc jle 
esc cbw blo bgt jne cwd jpe jng jeq sal cmp rcl blt nil lds 
div les jnl jlo jgt sar rep rcr jno jmp jnp hlt jpo jlt sub 
stc std ret jns int rol nop mul pop sti mov jnz ror out  
lahf call jnae jnbe sahf jnge bhis lock jnle xchg scas 
repe idiv jhis blos lods cmps iret wait popf imul jlos 
xlat loop into jcxz test push repz movs stos 
buncd scasb juncd lodsb cmpsb repne xlatb loope scasw 
pushf movsb lodsw cmpsw stosb repnz loopz movsw stosw 
loopne loopnz 


What immediately struck me is the elevated number of mnemonics.
After a close inspection I compiled next table for the supplemental mnemonics:



Enc
Intel mnemonics
Manx mnemonics
Description




70h
jo




71h
jno




72h
jb, jnae, jc
blo, jlo
lower


73h
jnb, jae, jnc
bhis, jhis
higher or same


74h
je, jz
beq, jeq
equal


75h
jne, jnz
bne
not equal


76h
jbe, jna
blos, jlos
lower or same


77h
jnbe, ja
bhi, jhi
higher


78h
js




79h
jns




7Ah
jp, jpe




7Bh
jnp, jpo




7Ch
jl, jnge
blt, jlt
less than


7Dh
jnl, jge
bge
greater or equal


7Eh
jle, jng
ble
less or equal


7Fh
jnle, jg
bgt, jgt
greater than


EBh
jmp
buncd, juncd
unconditionally




nil




Now I wonder why the author(s) added so many extra mnemonics. I understand that one would do this in order to ease the transition for people coming from another architecture like eg. 68k that does use beq, bne, bhi, blt, bge, ble, and bgt.

What I don't quite get is the addition of the longer-than-necessary buncd and juncd. (They could easily have picked bra instead.) Have there ever been assemblers around that already used buncd and juncd?

What is nil supposed to accomplish? It sits among the instructions but the assembler doesn't insert any code for it. Isn't prefixing a line with a semicolon much easier if we want to omit what is on a line or suppress anything from getting encoded?


The AS.EXE file (44448 bytes) bears the following copyright notice:

Copyright (C) 1984 by Manx Software Systems.
8086 Assembler Vers. 1.06D

The file came with an 8088 computer some 35 years ago and I never had a manual for it. Not surprising I barely used the software, except for today in order to verify the above mentioned table.

The mysterious AS.EXE is apparently the assembler distributed with the Aztec C compiler toolchain.  Most of these extra mnemonics are actually pseudo-instructions providing the ability to perform conditional jumps with word displacement, as encodings for such conditional jumps did not exist before the 386.  I am much less sure of the motivation for nil and buncd.  The former might presumably be useful as a placeholder for situations where an instruction is expected by the grammar, but none is actually intended by the programmer (something like the Python pass keyword); but then I am somewhat doubtful that any such situations ever actually arise.  The latter mnemonic, though, seems entirely redundant.
This is what the manual for version 4.10c of the toolchain has to say (page 31 in the assembler manual, numbered 206 in the PDF):

Most of the special instructions supported by as are conditional branch instructions, whose target location can be anywhere in the current code segment The standard conditional jump instructions require that the target address be inside a small interval of code centered around the jump instruction.
When a conditional branch instruction is assembled, the equivalent jump instruction will be generated if the target of the branch can be reached by the jump instruction. Otherwise, the assembler will generate two hardware instructions for the branch: an unconditional jump to the target (which can access any location in the code segment), preceded by a conditional jump around the unconditional jump. This preceding conditional jump tests for a condition that is the opposite of the one specified by the branch instruction.
The special branch instructions and their corresponding jump instructions are:



branch
jump




beq
je


bne
jne


blt
jl


ble
jle


bgt
jg


bge
jge


blo
jb


blos
jbe


bhi
ja


bhis
jae



The other special instructions supported by as are nil, which does nothing and which generates no code; and xlatb, which is the same as the standard xlat instruction, but which doesn’t require an operand, and which assumes that the translate table is in the segment pointed at by the DS segment register (ie, it won’t automatically output a segment override prefix).

I was not able to locate the manual for the 1.06d version; not for the 8086 target at least.

Nice find! It makes sense to have that branch lot escape the short distance.

This assembler is probably the backend for the C compiler, and so an instruction like nil makes sense. The compiler might need a keyword in place of any special character where no machine shall be generated.

@thebusybee Why would it need one?

@user3840170 Because in some stage the output to be generated is optimized to nothing, but the next stage requires something. Compilers can be astonishingly simple or even primitive.

@user3840170 you may need something to put a label on

@thebusybee I still don’t see it. Why can’t the compiler handle zero instructions just like any other number of instructions? It seems like a more primitive thing to do to handle degenerate cases uniformly instead of exceptionally.

@ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Now that is an argument. And it may even be relevant – the manual says that “A label is defined in the following ways: (1) in the name field of an instruction, followed by a ':'; (2) using a proc directive; (3) using a label directive.” – which implies that an instruction ought to be present, so a placeholder like that may be useful. But then, examples found elsewhere in the manual seem to contradict this: labels without an instruction on the same line appear every so often.

@user3840170 then my best bet is that this it to support some implementation detail of the compiler that this assembler was written for. If it generates a stream of instructions which may have labels, then this covers the corner case of a label with no actual instruction which may make flow control easier to generate.

@user3840170 Such old compilers go strange routes. Perhaps it cannot handle an empty instruction, not even as a comment string, just because it needs an actual mnemonic. -- Anyway, we are all speculating here, so let's stop the discussion. Without a developer of the software, or at least the source code, we will never know. -- It could as well be an equivalent to nop, simply on the pseudo-mnemonic meta level. But again, this is speculative.

Sadly Aztec c has not been open sourced so we cannot go check

There is always disassembly…

Well, Manx Software Systems you say? Wouldn't that be the Assembler used as part of Manx's Aztec C? Aztec C was not only one of the very early micro computer C compilers but also a cross platform tool as it supported 6502 (Apple II and others), 8080 and Z80 (CP/M) as well as, a bit later 8086 and 68000. The 8086 version was available for CP/M-86 as well as PC/MS-DOS. They were quite successful until MS also offered a C compiler and Apple went for other suppliers.
Now an Assembler intended as backend for a C-compiler can gain a lot from having synonyms matching what the compiler likes to produce. Especially as the names Intel used for their mnemonics aren't as great as they may have thought (*1). Also, coming from 6502 and x80 style branch/jump names may have helped porting parts of either - not to mention the hassles of conditional jumps past +/-128 bytes.
NIL may simply be a placeholder for code where no code is needed. Like purely to mark labels, or when it got optimized away. Depending on how the C compiler handles its intermediate objects, a token that simply does nothing might be the way to distinguish it from a non-existent element, so attributes for it (like address or sequence) can still be managed.
There is even an "Official Aztec C Museum" holding many of the original documentation and software versions. You might want to have a look there.

*1 - I just recently discovered a systematic issue (my own fault) with JL vs. JB in a 40 year old program after I finally understood what Intel did there :(

The insight that this assembler is intended to receive source generated by a compiler, and not a human is important.  These instructions are exactly what’s needed to abstract away the CPUs limitations until enough is known to actually emit the proper machine code.  Kneejerk reaction would be to implement them as macros - this is probably the most efficient way to do it
